# $row['column'] in PHP

Tags: php, rows

Hello guys I have seen a code with `$row['columnname']`.The code is

```
$myQuery = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '$tabname'";
$re = mysql_query($myQuery);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($re)){
     if(!empty ($row)){
                $col_name = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];

      $myQuery = "SELECT ".$col_name." FROM ".$tabname." WHERE sampleid='".$sid."'";
                echo "<br>".$myQuery;
                $reqq = mysql_query($myQuery);
                $roww = mysql_fetch_array($reqq);
                echo "<br>".$roww[$col_name];

                }
            }
```

My question is what is the use of `$row[]` in php?

Is it used to embed the column value like `$row['columnname']` or just adding a variable like `$row[$anyvariable]`.

Comment: Please note as well that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and `mysql` is deprecated in favor of `mysqli` or `PDO`. Please use those instead and use prepared statements!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called ***bracket notation***. `$row` is an array, which has properties. In this case, it has named properties, so it is an associative array. An associate array has key/value pairs. It looks like this:

```
$myArray = [
  'key' => 'value'
];
```

To echo the value of the property above, you would use `echo $myArray['key'];`

In the specific code you included, the property name is "COLUMN_NAME" and it has a value. The code assigns that value to the variable `$col_name`.

Here's another sample usage to help clarify all of this:

```
$people = [
  'Susan' => [
    'Age' => 24,
    'Phone' => '555-123-4567'
  ],
  'Jack' => [
    'Age' => 27,
    'Phone' => '555-9876-5432'
  ]
];

echo $people['Jack']['Age']; // 27
```

Comment: @codemania my answer somewhat differs from the others. It seemed to me you were asking about bracket notation. The other answers are more focused on the mysql.

Comment: @codemania If we're on the same page, then yes. Anything you're accessing like that is an array. You can also add to an array with `$myArray['someKey] = 'the new value';`

Comment: yeah i told about the bracket notation ..you answer somewhat helped me .i just need to know the use of $row[].My question is that what values can be applied inside the square brackets of $row['whichvaluehere'] ?

Comment: @codemania if you're writing properties, anything you want. You can `var_dump($theArray)` to see what properties it has and therefore what you can read from it.

Comment: You can put any key in there and if its value is present in the array, it will be returned

Comment: @codemania there are also numerical arrays which don't have named keys . They are indexed, like `$myArray[0]`, `$myArray[1]`, `$myArray[2]`, etc. You can just keep adding to the array with `$myArray[] = 'new value'` and that will be added at the end.

Comment: i didnt understood it really .@m59 can you please update ur answer with more information .I didnt understood the key here ..i just need to know what values can be put inside $row['values'] ? i just need to know how to use values inside square brackets ?

Comment: for example ..$row['anyvalue'] i just need to know how to use 'anyvalue' or how can we apply such a value inside $row array.

Comment: @codemania You're not understanding :) You can add or read properties with that syntax, it depends on if it exists already. We know `COLUMN_NAME` exists. If you do `$row['COLUMN_NAME'] = `new value'`, then you changed its value from whatever it was. If you do `$row['abc'] = 'whatever'` and it didn't exist before, then it is now part of the array. Whatever is in the array can be access using the same syntax. `echo $row['COLUMN_NAME']` prints the value stored there. Consider the example in my answer.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky yeah i know about arrays..is it same like array ..? can we declaire $row['somevalue'] = $varibale ?

Comment: Thanks m59 ..i got it ..:) ...can we add a name valuw with $row.like $row['somevalue'] = $vaubale ?

Answer (score 2):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($re)){
```

This statement loops over all the rows returned in your result set  `$re` and while looping, on every iteration you will get the current row as an array in your variable named `$row`, this name can be anything, it doesn't have to be `$row` necessarily.

Then

```
$col_name = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];
```

Is just reading `$row` as an array and picking up the value for the key `COLUMN_NAME`. This will be one of the columns that were returned by your query for each row of the result set. This also can be any name depending upon your query.

Answer (score 1):

it is from [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array)

it returns result array if your query/result was found, if not just FALSE instead

Answer (score 0):

Like it says on the [PHP site](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) :

> mysql_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both

It's not variables that would go inside the `$row[]` , it's the column name that you have called  in your `SELECT` query .

In your case, you have a `SELECT` query to return all the columns of a table. `'COLUMN_NAME'` is in fact really the name of a column in the table of `information_schema.column`

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` returns an array,

```
$row = [
  'column_name' => 'column_value'
]
```

so the statement

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array ($re))
```

will fetches the column names from information_schema.columns that will be stored into $col_name.

```
$col_name = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];
```

for more read [mysql_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array)