# Using square brackets and assigning variables in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have seen source code like:

```
$something = $sql['value']
```

I have searched a lot about it and I found that it's from arrays. But I didn’t understand the exact meaning.

For example,

```
$people = [

 'Susan' => [
    'Age' => 24,
'Phone' => '555-123-4567'
],

  'Jack' => [

  'Age' => 27,

  'Phone' => '555-9876-5432'

  ]
];

echo $people['Jack']['Age']; // 27
```

Can we write code like the following?

```
if(!empty($people)

    $something = $people['a value']
```

I just need to know how we can declare a variable and give a value in square brackets.

Comment: Please see PHP manual on arrays

Comment: Could you clarify, perhaps? What about accessing arrays indices puzzles you? The basic indices are numbers, like `$my_array[0];` but you can also use words or keys, as they are called, to do `$my_array["mrsnuggles"];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `$something = $people['a value']` it means you are assigning a value of the `$people` array having an index of `a value`.

So you don't have that and so it will throw you *undefined index error*.

You are using a nested associative array and you have to output using something like:

```
echo $people['Jack']['Age'];
```

---

As you wanted a brief example, say you have an array like

```
$people = array('name'=>'Jack');
```

Now, when you want to store the name in a variable, you use

```
$store_name = $people['name'];

echo $store_name; // Echoes "Jack"
```

Comment: can you explain more breifly .In which situatio we use $something = $people['a value'] ?

Comment: Thanks ..is it used on in arrays ?

Comment: Thanks a lot .can you do me a help please ...i have another doubt too ..what is $row also act like in this way ?..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423303/rowcolumn-in-php

Comment: @codemania You are storing the results fetched from the database to array, and later you echo them with keys, it's just like what I explained above

Comment: So can we use another varibales instead of $row .?

Comment: @codemania why not, you can, but make sure you change the variables here too `$row['COLUMN_NAME']` <---

Comment: you mean we must change the key value according to the condition ..right ?

Comment: Thanks alien have a look at here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429441/update-a-variable-on-click....SEE $user_data is not defined as an array but the value is given as   $username = $user_data['username'];..why is it like so ?

Comment: @codemania I can go on helping you but actually it won't help you, learn first, if you jump like this to advance topic, you will never learn

Comment: please tell me whats it ...i have learnt ..why is it not declaired as an array ?

Comment: as you explained above its applicable in arrays only ..but here $user_data is not declaired as array ?

Comment: In that code $username = $user_data['username']; is given .but $user_data is not declaired as an array ..so from where the value username is taken ?

Comment: i didnt get it ?..can you please explain why it is ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$people = array(
    'Susan' => array('Age' => 24, 'Phone' =>  '555-123-4567'),
    'Jack'  => array('Age' => 27, 'Phone' => '555-9876-5432')
);
```

Comment: It's same, the difference is the syntax, OP is using newer syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array` and write it like this

```
$people = array(
    'Susan' => array(
        'Age' => 24,
        'Phone' => '555-123-4567'
    ),
    'Jack' => array(
        'Age' => 27,
        'Phone' => '555-9876-5432'
    )
);

echo $people['Jack']['Age']; // 27


if(!empty($people)

    $something = $people['a value']
```

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets mean index, so $people['a value'] is a value that lays under the 'a value' index of the $people array.

Square brackets are also used as a shortcut for array().. [See it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772534/php-array-square-brackets-and-array-difference)-